# Portion of camera surface view is black after taking app from background

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

Hi I did a simple camera application with only a surface view inside of a frame layout, initially the preview occupies the full width of the screen but later when we press home button and take the app from background there is a small portion on the screen where it is black in color as shown in the attached image.

[image]

Code:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (camera == null) {
            initalizeCamera();
            cameraView.setmCamera(camera);

            Log.d("Tag", "onResume: Cam null;");

        } else {
            Log.d("Tag", "onResume: Cam not null;");
        }
        Log.d("Tag", "onResume: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        cameraView.stopUserPreview();
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;

        Log.d("Tag", "onPause: ");
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        cameraView.stopUserPreview();
        Log.d("Tag", "onStop: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Log.d("Tag", "onStart: ");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Tag", "onViewCreated: ");

        surfaceParent = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.surface_parent);
        initalizeCamera();
        cameraView = new CameraView(getContext());
        cameraView.setmCamera(camera);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setWidth((int) (480 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setHeight((int) (640 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsSurface = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getWidth(),
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getHeight());
        paramsSurface.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        cameraView.setLayoutParams(paramsSurface);
        surfaceParent.addView(cameraView);
        /*ViewTreeObserver vto = cameraView.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Log.d("Tag", "onGlobalLayout: " + cameraView.getWidth() + " " + cameraView.getHeight());
            }
        });*/
    }

    private void initalizeCamera() {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.setPreviewCallback(this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Tag", "initalizeCamera: Camera exception");
        }
    }
```

SurfaceView class:

```
public void setmCamera(Camera mCamera) {
    this.mCamera = mCamera;
    /*if (mHolder != null) {
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
    }*/
}

public CameraView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        /*getLayoutParams().height = ((MainActivity) context).getHeight();
        getLayoutParams().width = ((MainActivity) context).getWidth();*/
        //invalidate();
        if (mCamera != null && !previewRunning) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Tag", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.d("Tag", "surfaceCreated: ");
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }
    /*getLayoutParams().height = ((MainActivity) context).getHeight();
    getLayoutParams().width = ((MainActivity) context).getWidth();*/
    // stop preview before making changes
    if (mCamera != null) {
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            previewRunning = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Tag", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    Log.d("Tag", "surfaceChanged: " + width + " " + height);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    previewRunning = false;
    Log.d("Tag", "surfaceDestroyed: ");
}

public void startUserPreview() {
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    if (mCamera != null) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void stopUserPreview() {
    mHolder.addCallback(null);

}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/surface_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: what is the log output after onResume()? Does camera becomes null or not?

Comment: I am initializing camera in onResume, camera is not null after on resume. After on resume surfaceCreated and surfaceChanged are called .